# FScore, Precision, Recall and Accuracy of textual data in Python

Tags: python, nltk, precision, text-classification, precision-recall

I am blank how to calculate **Fscore, Precision , Recall and accuracy** in Python. I have an excel file, having "**1172 rows x 3 columns**". Where *column 1 contains the Original Words*, *Column 2 contains Gold Lemma* and *Column 3 contains the tested Lemma*.

[Image is attached of excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5J7z.png)

How can i calculate the Fscore, Precision , Recall and accuracy in Python. I am using Jupytor
My data is in UTF-8 format, Language is Urdu

Comment: Can't you compare columns 2 and 3 (compare the strings in each corresponding cell) in Python to derive your scores? Because there isn't a classifier don't know how you'd define Precision and Recall though, could you elaborate a bit? Precision is True Positives/ (True Positives + False Positives). In your context, what is a False Positive or a False Negative?

Comment: @picmate actually i am confused. I dont know the solution. But i have to calculate fscores atleast. But i can't figure out how to compare and calculate. there are no TP and FP's . can you please let me know how to find fscore?

Comment: Not sure whether you are looking for F1 or Fbeta. But, this is the definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_score. Basically you calculate the Precision and Recall and then calculate the F score from that. I'll try to put together a solution for your example

Comment: Since there isn't False Positives or False negatives, Precision and Recall would be 1. Then the F1 score is again 1. However, the accuracy will be different. Accuracy is the number of correct predictions/ all predictions. This will be the letters in column 2 and 3 that match divided by all letters in column 2.